# Rails 4 calling nested associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm pretty new to rails but started having this issue today which i haven't experienced before. Currently working on an application with a few nested associations. While i can create and add save these nested associations through the parent association i can't seem to call on elements from the associated model very well. I can see the information has been saved but when I call for it i get the name of the model not what is in the name column of the table.

brew.rb

```
    class Brew < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :fermentables
     has_many :extras
     has_many :hops
     has_many :yeasts

     accepts_nested_attributes_for :hops

     end
```

hop.rb

```
     class Hop < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :brew
      end
```

show.html.erb

```
      <%= @brew.name %>
       <%= @brew.story %>
       <%=  @brew.walkthrough %>
       <%=  @brew.hops.name%>
```

The show displays mostly everything just fine except when it comes to @brew.hops.name. It only displays Hop. 
When I go into rails console I can see that the name had been saved. But only when I do something like.

```
   t = Brew.last
   t.hops.name
```

results only in the word "hops"

but if i just say

```
   t.hops
```

i get

```
      ` SELECT "hops".* FROM "hops" WHERE "hops"."brew_id" = ?  [["brew_id", 28]]
        => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Hop id: 6, name: "Warrior",
        brew_id: 28, created_at: "2013-06-09 22:09:19", updated_at: "2013-06-09    22:09:19">]> `
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brew and hops are in relation one-to-many, so `@brew.hops` returns set of all hops belonging to `@brew`. So, if you want to display all associated `hops` names, you should do something like this:

```
<% @brew.hops.each do |hop| %>
  <%= hop.name %><br />
<% end %>
```

Comment: Oh wow. Thanks so much I can't believe I didn't catch that. very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`t.hops` returns an object representing the `has_many` association itself, not an individual Hop record, and calling the `name` method on that association object gives the name of the class of the associated model (the Hop class).

So I think you are wanting to **iterate** over the list of associated Hops and print each of their names:

```
<%- @brew.hops.each do |hop| -%>
  Hop: <%= hop.name %>
<%- end -%>
```

Comment: Oh wow. Thanks so much I can't believe I didn't catch that. very much appreciated.

Comment: Please mark one of the answers as "accepted" to close the question if you're satisfied, thanks